# Automation of MapInfo layer changes

Tags: qgis, mapinfo

I am working with MapInfo files.

I have to make a lot of geometrical changes and each geometry change needs a corresponding change in multiple layers of tabular data.

I am looking at automating the same in QGIS.
for e.g. I want to drag and drop point geometry data from one point to another, edit line geometry data by adding a new vertex, or move line from one place to another. And during these user actions, I want to update the MapInfo tabular data automatically.

How can I do this in QGIS customizations?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: I think your first decision is which of MapInfo Pro, QGIS and a custom web application you wish to ask about in this particular question.  You can always ask about the others in separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed custom QGIS plugins using Python which was useful for making manual updates like move coordinates, change shape etc. and automatically make attribute updates. Used pyqt library.